# Central Limit Theorem interpretation confusion

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

I was wonder in some problems, the central limit theorem is Z = root(n)((xbar - mu)/sigma), however in some cases, the root n is not there. In this case per se, the root n is not there as I checked the answer online. If possible can someone explain why there isn't a root n in this case.

https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/let-y-denote-the-sum-of-the-observations-of-a-random-sample-of-size-12-from-a-distribution-having-pm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we are interested in $Y=\sum X_i$ having Variance $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\sum_i \operatorname{Var} (X_i)=12(2.92)=n\sigma^2$.

If instead we were interested in the mean $\bar Y=\frac Y {12}$ it would have variance $\frac {\operatorname{Var}(Y)} {12^2}=\frac{2.92}{12}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

The root n comes from the second part where $\frac{\bar X-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n}=\sqrt n\frac{\bar X-\mu}{\sigma}$ if we are dealing with sample mean but here we are dealing with a sum furthermore we have already incorporated the $\sqrt n$ in the calculation of the variance of $Y$ so that it why does not appear again in part 2.

So depending on if you are interested in the sum of a sample or the mean of the sample, the $n$ will be in different places. The central limit theorem applies to both cases.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I was wondering how is it already incorporates in the calculation of the variance Y

Comment: You see variance of Y is 12(2.92)=nVar(X). So the central limit theorem would show $\frac{Y-\mu} {\sqrt n \sigma}$. But it’s the denominator already has been calculated so it’s just Sqrt(Var(Y))=sqrt(35)

Comment: Yes I see it now. Thank You, but just for confirmation, its because we are looking for Y which asks for summation instead of sample mean which is why we don't have you divide by root n

Comment: Yes. For the summation you multiply by the sqrt n, for the sample mean you divide by the sqrt n, to the variance of the thing being summed, to get the variance of the summation or mean. But it can all be found using the property of variance.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation :D